# Monorepo with custom hooks throws: could not find react-redux context valuel please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, monorepo, lerna

I have a monorepo React setup built using lerna tool where I have one package that is storing the Redux state and exports `createStore` method. There is also one custom hook:

```
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux';

export const useSignInEffect = (effect: EffectCallback) => {
const isSignedIn = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.auth.isSignedIn);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isSignedIn) {
    return effect();
  }
 }, [isSignedIn]);
};
```

Everything else works well, redux store besides this hook where I get the following error. Do I need to do something additional here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This most commonly means that your build system is pulling in multiple copies of `react` or `react-redux`.  Make sure that any "library"-type packages are set to use `react` and `react-redux` as peer dependencies, not full dependencies, and that only one copy of each is in your app bundle.

Comment: Indeed that was the issue, somehow the peerDependencies were incorrect. Thank you very much @markerikson